# Can I add color to FitNesse test table cells?

Tags: fitnesse

I would like to be able to add coloured backgrounds to FitNesse table cells (sometimes entire rows) to enhance their readability. I'm happy if these colours are overwritten when a test page is run. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Since this is pretty old, I'll comment instead of post this as an answer. I was able to easily color rows using a little jQuery and `!- -!` on the fitnesse pages to denote html. This gives you a little more freedom to style based on logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply custom styles to any fitnesse cell by using the

!style_(text)

widgit.  Where (text) is the name of some css class you have defined. You can see the various options for [formatting the fitnesse wiki pages](http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.QuickReferenceGuide#CharacterFORMATTING) at [fitnesse.org](http://www.fitnesse.org)

EDIT : It looks as though the style widgit is only useful for formatting text not in a fixture table. For example:

```
!|Store Data Dictionary Table|VALUE_SET_VALUE|
|!style_strike(ValueSetID)|Code|Label|
|MCODESET|1|RESPONSE1|
|MCODESET|2|RESPONSE2|
|MCODESET|3|RESPONSE3|
|MCODESET|4|RESPONSE4|
```

does not set the style of ValueSetId to the strike class.  But removing the ! from the table itself like so does work:

```
|Store Data Dictionary Table|VALUE_SET_VALUE|
|!style_strike(ValueSetID)|Code|Label|
|MCODESET|1|RESPONSE1|
|MCODESET|2|RESPONSE2|
|MCODESET|3|RESPONSE3|
|MCODESET|4|RESPONSE4|
```

You could also try applying the style directly like so:

```
!|Store Data Dictionary Table|VALUE_SET_VALUE|
|!-<span class="strike">ValueSetID</span>-!|Code|Label|
|MCODESET|1|RESPONSE1|
|MCODESET|2|RESPONSE2|
|MCODESET|3|RESPONSE3|
|MCODESET|4|RESPONSE4|
```

This uses the widgit that outputs the HTML tags.  I tried applying it to the row but it did not work though :( You might have to tag each individual element.

Comment: Ideally I'd like to be able to color the background of the cell rather than specific pieces of text. In particular I want to be able to highlight a whole row. Can I use !style for this too?

Comment: I've tried various permutations, but I'm not having any luck. The documentation you refer to says 'The style of text will be the CSS class <someStyle>' which suggests that 'text' is not the style name but the data you want to be styled. Could you include an example, please?

Comment: See my comment Matthew.  I agree the documentation is confusing.  I really wish UncleBob would put some time into making Fitnesse useful rather than developing Slim (which does mostly the same stuff as fitnesse just with a different backend).

Comment: Happy to help, sorry for the delayed response!